# Does laplace transform tanht exists?

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to calculate laplace transform of tanht. My question is that does its laplace transform exists?

And if exists then what will be its laplace transform?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Laplace transform?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: The hyperbolic tangent is a bounded smooth function, so its transform certainly exists in the whole positive half-plane. I doubt it has a closed-form expression.

Answer (score 3):

We're interested in $L(s):=\int_0^\infty\tanh t\exp(-st)dt$. The integrand is $\sim t$ for small $t$, and $\sim\exp(-st)$ for large $t$, so $L$ converges for all $s>0$. For such $s$,$$\begin{align}L(s)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\exp(-2t)}{1+\exp(-2t)}\exp(-st)dt\\&\stackrel{\ast}{=}\sum_{k\ge0}(2-\delta_{k0})(-1)^k\int_0^\infty\exp(-(s+2k)t)dt\\&=-\frac1s+\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^k}{s/2+k}\\&=-\frac1s+\Phi(-1,\,1,\,s/2)\end{align}$$[in terms of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28-1%29%5En%2F%28x%2Bn%29+from+0+to+infinity) the [Lerch zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Definition). Note $\stackrel{\ast}{=}$ uses the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Would you please help with some instructing words for education purpose? Assume that DCT is for Direct Comparison Test which is not elementary for me.

Comment: @MathArt Apologies for the confusion: I had another DCT in mind, so I've edited my answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\tanh x=1-2\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^ke^{-2kx}$$

so that, term by term,

$$\mathcal L\tanh x=\frac1s+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{s+2k}.$$

Comment: This matches @J.G.'s answer.

Comment: Do the terms involving $\frac{1}{s}$ match?

Comment: @mjw: I think so, look closer.

Comment: Yes.  Does match.  Was sitting too far from the screen, apparently.

Comment: For a moment, I was lost at the power series expansion too. Note that $x$ needs to be non-negative for Laplace transform, $\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=e^{-2x}\frac{1}{1-(-e^{-2x})}=e^{-2x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^ke^{-2kx}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^ke^{-2(k+1)x}$.